# Append a string starting with coma ',somestring' at the third line after matching pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I need a shell script to append a string starting with coma ',somestring' at the end of the 3rd line after the matching pattern using `sed` or `awk`.

Here is an example:

Before

```
Pattern
somestuff
anotherstuff, random
```

After

```
Pattern
somestuff 
anotherstuff, random,Somestring
```

Comment: This is your 2nd question with no attempt made to solve the problem yourself. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '/Pattern/ {f=3} f--==1 {$0=$0",Somestring"} 1' file
Pattern
somestuff
anotherstuff, random,Somestring
```

If `Pattern` is found, set counter to `3`
Reduce counter with one and test if its `1`
When its true, add text. Final print all lines.

Comment: `f--==1` -> `!--f` for the beauty of shortness (I prefer your answer anyway ;) ).

Comment: @jotne thx, that worked fine, simple question where in the expression does it say to go next line until counter =1? And what the '1' at the end of the expression stand for?

Comment: @Khalid awk has a test, then action.  With only `1` or any number, the test is true.  If its true do the default action, and that is print the line.  `1` = `1 {print $0}`

Answer (score -1):

Input

```
Pattern
somestuff 
anotherstuff, random
```

Using awk :

```
awk -v pattern="Pattern" -v n_line=3 -v addstr=" ,somestring" 'line{line+=1}($0 ~ pattern){line=1}(line==n_line){$0 = $0 addstr}1' file
```

Output :

```
Pattern
somestuff 
anotherstuff, random ,somestring
```

To replace file, if you have gawk > 4.1.0 use :

```
gawk -i inplace -v pattern="Pattern" -v n_line=3 -v addstr=" ,somestring" 'line{line+=1}($0 ~ pattern){line=1}(line==n_line){$0 = $0 addstr}1' file
```

Otherwise :

```
awk -v pattern="Pattern" -v n_line=3 -v addstr=" ,somestring" 'line{line+=1}($0 ~ pattern){line=1}(line==n_line){$0 = $0 addstr}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: That worked just fine for me thx, 
The only improvement, i need is to ignore commented lines starting with # containing the Pattern, is there a way i can place that ?

Comment: Sure you just need to replace `($0 ~ pattern)` with `($0 ~ "^[^#]*"pattern)`. You can do the same with @Jotne answer and replace `/Pattern/` with `/^[^#]*Pattern/`.